# AJAX post data is not received in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've recently started learning PHP from the very basics. After following some tutorials I'm trying to learn something and here I'm facing a problem and after visiting different URLs for similar issues but couldn't solve mine.

I have a page where user enters data in form and that data is added in a grid (table) by using Add button. On Save button the table data is sent to the PHP using Ajax. Along with this table data there are 3 text fields on the same form whose data is not added in that table and those text fields data also being sent to the PHP by using Ajax Call. Here is my Save button code.

```js
$("#save").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        debugger
        if (!iQuantity || !iDiscount) { // This is checking validation.
            $("#message").fadeIn(1000).html(`<div class="alert alert-warning">Please fill all the fields</div>`);
            $("#message").fadeOut(3000);
        } 
              
        if ($("#amountPayable").val() === "" || $("#amountPayable").val() == 0 || $("#amountPaid").val() === "" || $("#amountPaid").val() == 0 
            || $("#discountGiven").val() === "" ) {

            $("#message").fadeIn(1000).html(`<div class="alert alert-warning">Please fill all the fields</div>`);
            $("#message").fadeOut(3000);

        } else {

                var tableData = [];
                $('#addTable tbody tr').each(function () {
                    debugger
                    var rowData = {
                        itemId: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(),    // first column in row is trainee  (on index 0)
                        saleId: $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(),   // second column in row is title
                        qty: $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text(),   // 4th column in row is attend
                        amount: $(this).find('td:eq(4)').text(),  // 5th column in row is trainer                        
                    };
                    tableData.push(rowData);
                });

            var formFields = {   // This takes text fields data
                amountPayable: $("#amountPayable").val(),
                amountPaid: $("#amountPaid").val(),
                discountGiven: $("#discountGiven").val(),
            };

            // Here I'm making object of both above objects.
            var dataToSend = {
                td: JSON.stringify(tableData), // Grid data
                ff: JSON.stringify(formFields), // Text fields data
            };
            

            console.log("ok");
            $("#message").html("");
            debugger
            $.ajax({
                url: "../add-pages/add-orders.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: dataToSend,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                
                success: function (receivedData) {
                    debugger
                    var dt = receivedData;
                    $('#message').fadeIn(1000).html(receivedData);
                    $("#message").fadeOut(3000);

                    // --------------------------------------------- For Claring the Form Fields, ---------------------------------------------
                    $(':input', '#addOrdersData')
                        .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
                        .val('')
                        .prop('checked', false)
                        .prop('selected', false);
                    
                    $("#update").attr("disabled", true);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

And here is my PHP code where I'm receiving the code:

```
    <?php
     date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');

     $tableData = json_decode($_POST['td']); // Grid data
     $ff = json_decode($_POST['ff']); // Grid data
   ?>
```

The error I received in PHP is:

> Warning: Undefined array key "td" in C:\xampp\htdocs\superStore\add-pages\add-orders.php on line 4

Please guide me where the mistake is happening.

Thank you very much, SOF.

Comment: `contentType: false,` tells jQuery to not send any `Content-Type` header at all - so PHP has no reason to assume this _was_ actually a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, and will therefor not populate $_POST. Remove that.

Comment: What is `debugger` for?

Comment: Putting JSON inside a url-encoded variable really doesn't make a lot of sense either. If you want to send JSON then set the application/json content-type and send one JSON string, by itself containing all the data, in the request body. Then see [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php) for how to process that in PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `contentType: false` tells jQuery to not send any Content-Type header at all - so PHP has no reason to assume this was actually a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, and will therefor not populate `$_POST`. And `processData: false` tells jQuery not to automatically convert the provided data into form-url-encoded format either, so it will just send the stringified version of your object, which by default in JS is `[object Object]` - and that is clearly no use to PHP. Generally those two options are only useful when trying to upload files and/or raw FormData objects.

But even we fixed that, putting JSON inside a url-encoded variable really doesn't make a lot of sense either. Why mix different data formats and risk encoding issues etc. when you could just use one format very easily?

If you want to send JSON then it's better to set the `application/json` content-type and send one JSON string, by itself containing all the data, in the request body. Then you can adjust your PHP code to receive the JSON-encoded data.

For example:

JavaScript:

```
var dataToSend = JSON.stringify({
    td: tableData, 
    ff: formFields,
});

$.ajax({
  url: "../add-pages/add-orders.php",
  method: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: dataToSend,
  success: function (receivedData) {
    var dt = receivedData;
    $('#message').fadeIn(1000).html(receivedData);
    $("#message").fadeOut(3000);

    //--------------------------------------------- For Claring the Form Fields, ---------------------------------------------
    $(':input', '#addOrdersData')
      .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
      .val('')
      .prop('checked', false)
      .prop('selected', false);
                    
    $("#update").attr("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

PHP:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data); //just for debugging purposes

//and then, for example, if you need to:
$tableData = $data["td"];
$ff = $data["ff"];
```

References:

- [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)
- [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: ADyson, there is a lot of knowledge for me in this single reply. You've filled my plate with very finely grain information for my future reference. If i didn't understand on something, so can I further ask here in your reply?

Comment: Yes please feel free to ask for clarification if you need  it

Comment: you said that **But even we fixed that, putting JSON inside a url-encoded variable really doesn't make a lot of sense either. Why mix different data formats and risk encoding issues etc. when you could just use one format very easily?**

What does it mean, I didn't get it at all?

Comment: @user87 Well it's a bit like sending a letter where you write the envelope and all the headings in English, but then you put part of the content inside in French, for no particular reason or advantage.  Your `dataToSend` object was a JavaScript object with JSON strings inside it. Then when you send that via AJAX, jquery automatically converts the JavaScript object to form-url-encoded format (i.e. `name1=value1&name2=value2` etc) by default, in order to transmit it. So because you have JSON inside that, you end up with this Frankenstein hybrid of two different data formats, which is silly...

Comment: ...because it's more code effort to create it, it's more code effort to decode it, and occasionally you can run into problems where the formats clash and you just end up with invalid / unparseable data. Whereas you can just send the whole request in one format or another. Your coded would have ended up with a mash-up something like: `td=[{"itemId":"xfsdf","saleId":"hfghfgh","qty":"dgfhfgh","amount":"hgethrthfgh"}]&ff={"amountPayable":22,"amountPaid":1324,"discountGiven":43343}`

Comment: ...whereas if you encode the whole thing as a coherent JSON object you get `{"td":[{"itemId":"xfsdf","saleId":"hfghfgh","qty":"dgfhfgh","amount":"hgethrthfgh"}],"ff":{"amountPayable":22,"amountPaid":1324,"discountGiven":43343}}` which you can then decode in PHP with a single call to `json_decode()` (instead of two separate ones) and get a usable object. Plus it's much easier to read and understand the payload, easier to test against it, etc etc.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>     data: dataToSend,
>     processData: false,
>     contentType: false,
> ```

You've told jQuery **not** to process the data (so XHR is going to convert your object to the string `[object Object]`, which is useless) and to not override the `Content-Type` (so XHR is going to set it to `text/plain` and PHP won't even try to parse the data).

Don't do that.

---

Aside:

> ```
> var dataToSend = {
>     td: JSON.stringify(tableData), // Grid data
>     ff: JSON.stringify(formFields), // Text fields data
> };
> ```

If you send PHP URL Encoded Form Data with the right naming conventions (e.g. `td[foo][bar][3]`) then PHP will automatically parse that into associative arrays inside `$_POST`.

If you pass `jQuery.ajax` a nested object then it will automatically convert the data structure to that PHP naming convention.

You can skip all your JSON encoding and decoding.

Comment: @Questin, Thank you very much and so nice of you.

Respected Quentin, I didn't understand fully on the text you mentioned after your 2nd code snippet. Can I have this honor to have it in more simple and plain english. Plus how to properly understand this XHR and contentType and processData things?

Comment: Delete the two lines I told you not to use.

Comment: Yeah Quentin, I did and it solved the problem. 
Thank you very much.